# SQL Server 2016 SP2, unable to shrink database, even after emptying primary file

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

We are running SQL Server 2016 SP2 CU15. For years we have set up test environments by pulling down a production backup and removing a lot of the data, then shrinking the database. For some reason this stopped working.

I ran a script to rebuild every index on the database, and added indexes to any heaps. This should have moved them up in the file, allowing me to shrink it.  When I run this `DBCC SHRINKFILE (N'FileName' , 1000000)` nothing happens. Because we are removing a lot of space, I am only trying to remove 100GB or so in a single run.

Out of desperation I added a second file to the primary file group then ran this
 `DBCC SHRINKFILE (N'FileName' , EMPTYFILE).`
This moved all but a few system tables out of the file and its now 99% empty. But it still wont do anything when I shrink it.

Before and after moving the objects to a new file, I ran the script from this link to identify the last object in the file group.  https://itectec.com/database/sql-server-sql-server-identifying-object-closest-to-the-end-of-a-datafile/
both times it returned:

```
Table:[sys].[sysrscols]

Index:[clst]
```

as a precaution I also ran `DBCC CHECKDB WITH NO_INFOMSGS` It did not return any issues.

Edit: It might be worth noting that we have about 3k tables and 700k columns. The initial restored backup was 1,167,907mb. We were successfully able to shrink it to 1,148,200mb, but we still have 800mb of free space.

Comment: Are you trying to shrink the data files or the log files? Have you tried setting the database to `SINGLE_USER` (in order to force other transactions and connections to close)

Comment: I am trying to shrink the data file, I have tried in single user mode. Also for fun I detached the database and attached it back to a different SQL instance.

Comment: I tried to repro this by triggering autogrow with a user table, triggering autogrow by adding a bunch of metadata (creating thousands of tables), then dropping the user table and shrinking.  The metadata was relocated to the beginning of the file and the unused space was eliminated.

Comment: @JohnPaulWelther, did you ever get this to work?